# SAS PHREG - assessing proportional hazards with delayed entry

Tags: sas, cox-regression

I am using a Cox proportional hazards model (`PHREG`) in SAS. I have used the `(t1,t2)*event` specification to indicate the age at which an individual came into the risk set and the age at which s/he left as described [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_phreg_sect032.htm).

I am trying to figure out how to correctly test/assess the proportional hazards assumption for my primary predictor. My initial guess is to include an interaction between the predictor of interest and `log(t2-t1)` but I'd like some confirmation beyond my own gut. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I could be entirely wrong, but if you have a time dependent variable you don't meet the Proportional Hazards assumption.

Comment: Thanks for this comment! I looked into it more and you're right, once there are time-varying variables the model is no longer a proportional hazards model. It's still unclear to me whether the time-fixed variables need to meet the PH assumption under this circumstance, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, check graphically and/or use tests.

[Here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/examples/asa/test_proportionality.htm) is a nice guide I found on how to do that. What I'd do is use a Harrell test and check that Schoenfeld residuals graph is 'horizontal' but I'm not sure whether you can do it with SAS or not : I never did (I used R) and that's not in the guide.

However, what you propose seems to be fine too (it's the second presented way).

Comment: Thanks, I've used that resource in the past but most of it pertains to the more traditional time-scale specification. I'm trying to figure out how to deal with the PH assumption with the (t1,t2)*event specification (i.e. time-varying covariates).